# How can we see the alien, who are travelling in light speed?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, speed, space-travel

If aliens has the technology to travel in speed of light ,How can we see them with our 'below the speed of light' technology?. Because when we see that(!),definitely it will not be in its place.Is there any technology to identify light speed object.(ignore relativity theory).

Comment: We already have a technology to "travel" at the speed of light: radio and tv. I am sure you have heard about them?

Comment: Yeah, but you can't chase a car with another car, both are travelling in light speed(just a imagination), when one is started after the other.

Comment: Of course not, as soon as one car reaches the speed of light, the entire universe collapses into a black hole of infinite mass around it. Duh!

Comment: Well since we're being so darn hypothetical, we'd use [*sensors*](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Sensor).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about science fiction and not physics.

Comment: @CuriousOne The good news is, the infinite mass would only expand at the speed of light, so parts of the expanding universe would remain unaffected.   Kinda like this:   https://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/140/problems.png  (Source)   http://what-if.xkcd.com/140/

Comment: @userLTK: The bad news is that by Karlhoff's Third Law somebody always had every idea way before you, so it's only a matter of time before we get sucked into somebody else's car hole.

Comment: they are travelling in light speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, why not.

Unknowns aside, if an object moves towards you at faster than the speed of light, you won't see it coming, or, perhaps more accurately, you can watch it coming after it reaches or passes you, but it will look like it's moving away from you even though it's already reached you.

What this means is, if aliens are planning an attack on earth and flying towards us faster than light, we won't see them coming and there's no known or even theoretical technology that would enable us to see them coming.  They would have the complete element of surprise, provided they have the technology to both move that fast, and stop once they get here.

We could see them fly away from us, a bit, though they'd fly away so fast it might look like they just vanished, but we could see parts of the side and parts of the front of their ship, not the part that was facing us as it flew away.   We'd only see light that reflected off it towards us, mostly we'd see the side of the ship.

And, at faster than the speed of light, it might actually look inverted.  Any lettering on the ship might read backwards as well as warped as it flew past or away from us.

Here's a pretty gif to give an idea of near light speed and how things appear to bend and twist.  There are better images out there, but I couldn't find any.

http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/relrot_640x480.gif

Here's a fun little question.  If you're in a ship that's impossibly traveling at faster than the speed of light, and, not an Alcubierre drive but just an impossible velocity through un-warped space, if you're on that ship, could you see yourself in a mirror?  :-).

I don't think you could.